# How do I find selfor in Octave?

Tags: neural-network, octave, unsupervised-learning

I need to implement unsupervised neural network using Octave. For that, I need to use "selforgmap" function. How do I find that function in octave or what are the packages include this function?

When I use "selforgmap", I got an error like this.

> > selforgmap

error: 'selforgmap' undefined near line 1 column 1

> > help selforgmap

error: help: 'selforgmap' not found

Comment: Is this some homework or on a course? What have you done so far? Do you want us to google it for you? Have you found the octave-forge nnet package and the recent discussion for a new nnet which uses googles tensorflow? One GSoC student currently has started a new nnet for Octave, see https://bitbucket.org/cittiberto/octave-nnet/src

Answer (score 0):

As of now there does not appear to be any implementation of `selforgmap` in octave or any of it's packages. The current neural net package, nnet, can be found at [Octave Forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/nnet/) and the Function Reference link will show you everything currently included.

The [link](http://bitbucket.org/cittiberto/octave-nnet/src) Andy commented with above to a current reworking if the nnet package also does not currently include `selforgmap`, but this could obviously change. The included function files can be seen inside the `inst` folder.

if MATLAB's `selforgmap` is not an option for you, you will either need to code your own implementation or switch bto another programming language. A quick search does reveal [a Python implementation of `selforgmap`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selforgmap) that may serve your purpose.